# How to compute the errors between two matrices of normal vectors?

Tags: matlab, matrix, normals

I have two matrices. One contains the correct values of xyz normal vectors.

The second matrix contains estimated normal vector values. I need to know how different these vectors are from the other matrix.

Matrices are of the form:

```
[X1 Y1 Z1; X2 Y2 Z2; ...; Xn Yn Zn]
```

I was going to compute the absolute error, relative error, and root mean squared error.

I am relatively new to matlab, but I made an attempt with the following code:

```
abs_err = @(real, estimate) mae(estimate - real);
rel_err = @(real, estimate) sum(sum(abs((estimate-real)./real)));
rms_err = @(real, estimate) sqrt((sum(real(:)-estimate(:)).^2)/length(real(:)));
```

Where real and estimate are nx3 matrices.

I believe absolute is correct.

Relative error returns infinity with my dataset. Also, the inner sum produces a 1 row by 3 column matrix, but I'm not sure if summing those values is the correct way to get the error for a vector.

RMSE returns a fairly high value of 7.3, but I'm not sure if that is due to my data set or error in the calculation.

So, any advice on calculating these errors or where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Relative error will give you infinity if any element in `estimate` and its corresponding element in the same position in `real` are both 0. Your RMSE calculation looks correct.  `mae` I don't know what the actual computation performs because you haven't made that available to us.

Comment: mae is a built in matlab function that I wasn't 100% sure I was using correctly, but the values seemed right. I suppose it is possible that there are some 0 values in real and estimate for the relative, I will check to see if I can remove those. I just wasn't sure if this was a good way to compare errors for such small vectors.

Comment: `mae` is part of the Neural Network Toolbox.  That's why I couldn't find it.... in any case, for relative errors, remove instances where both real and estimated values are 0 and try again. Otherwise it looks like you implemented it properly.

Comment: Didn't realize that was part of the neural network toolbox. I just did a quick google search for it. I'll need to change that part, but it shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for the help.